# Python Pandas Compound Aggregate not equal to Sum of Individual Assets Compounded

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Having a strange issue that skirts the line between stat/math and programming (I'm unsure what the root issue is).

I have a dataframe of returns by asset by month. Here's a small snapshot of the dataframe:

```
Strategy       Theme                   Idea    month           PnL
   Event    Catalyst  European Oil Services  2019-05 -1.412264e-10
   Event    Catalyst  European Oil Services  2019-06 -2.688968e-08
   Event    Catalyst                   None  2019-06  1.546945e-08
   Event         M&A                   None  2019-06  2.128868e-08
Fundamental  5G Rollout               Intelsat  2019-01  1.375019e-02
```

Now, when I group by month and sum, then compound the result, I get the answer I'd expect, and what I am able to replicate in excel:

```
x = df.groupby(['month']).sum()
total_pnl = x.compound()['PnL']
```

Gets me my excepted result of 4.16%. So far so good. However, taking the same dataframe, and compounding the individual Ideas, then summing, yields a different answer: 5.89%

```
dfx = df.pivot_table(index='month',columns=['Strategy','Theme','Idea'],values='PnL')
dfx = dfx.fillna(0.0)
dfx = dfx.compound()
dfx = dfx.reset_index(drop=False)
dfx.columns= ['Strategy','Theme','Idea','PnL']

total_pnl = sum(dfx['PnL'])
```

At first, I thought it was simply that it is not mathematically acceptable to compound individual returns then sum them, but a simple example I did in excel proved to me that the two methods should be the same. I then checked in excel if having 0 returns on any given month would be a problem -- it isn't.

Now I've been scratching my head for a couple hours trying to figure out why these numbers don't match when I do it in Python, while my simple excel example shows me they should.

Can you think of any caveats that I'm not taking into account that may be causing this?

Comment: The data you've supplied doesn't reproduce the problem.  Can you provide a small sample of data that, if used in your code, reproduces the issue?

Comment: Also, I can't tell without more data, but this is possibly an example of [Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't think it's Simpson's Paradox, but am also not able to reproduce a working code example that mimics what I'm seeing. Leaves me to believe it's the fault of something very idiosyncratic in my large dataset, and with no leads at to what that may be, tough to diagnose it at a granular level.

Comment: If you randomly subset your dataset, does any subset reproduce the issue?  You could write a short subsetting loop to check.